# Exclude a single file from sourceSets used in dependeny

Tags: java, gradle

I have `projectA` that have these lines in its Gradle build file:

```
sourceSets {
    kaitaiGenerated.java.srcDirs = ['src/kaitai']
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/kaitai/src']
        }
    }
}
```

`projectB` depends on many of the classes that are defined in `projectA`.

Its Gradle build file have the following:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = [project(':projectA').sourceSets.main.java, 'src/main/java']
            exclude '**/Main.java'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":projectA")
    // ...
}
```

The `exclude` doesn't seem to work, as I'm still getting conflicts as a result of its inclusion.

What's the best solution to get this working?

EDIT: Both projects are Spring boot.

Comment: Do you have any resources declaration that is causing the exclusion to be ignored? In that case add exclude there as well? Can you try excluding by package name such as: com.company.module/** and see exclusion is happening?

Comment: @fiveelements I can't add the exclusion on `projectA` since the class is needed for the `projectA` app.

Comment: I meant all these in project B. Yes, I understand you won't do it in project A.Can you try mentioning the full package (just to see if that works). If not then something else is causing the exclusion to be skipped.

Comment: @fiveelements Tried, doesn't work.